# -1 Record Inserted error

Tags: php, mysql

My code is showing -1 Record Inserted error and not inserting the fields to database. Any thoughts of why is it doing this?

```
  <?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$con=new dbconnect();
$con->connect();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if($_POST) {

    $users_name = $_POST['name'];
    $users_email = $_POST['email'];
    $users_website = $_POST['website'];
    $users_comment = $_POST['content'];

    $users_name = htmlspecialchars($users_name);
    $users_email = htmlspecialchars($users_email);
    $users_website = htmlspecialchars($users_website);
    $users_comment = htmlspecialchars($users_comment);


$postid = $_GET['id'];

$sSql = "INSERT INTO comments
 ( post_id, name, email, website,content)
 VALUES ($postid, '$users_name',
        '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment' )";

    mysql_query($sSql);
    $update=mysql_affected_rows();
    echo "<h2>$update Record Inserted</h2><br />";
    echo '<h2> Your Comment is submitted</h2><br />';
}
?>
```

For some reason, the comments table is not getting updated. I am new to programming in mySQL and PHP. Any suggestions would be of so much help to me. Thanks.

Comment: One thing you can always do is `echo $sSql` and see if the query looks like what you want it to.

Comment: in completion to what @sachleen said; take the query and run it directly in MySQL (PhpMyAdmin or Navicat or anything) because it will give you better error messages (better as in Googleable).

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not meant for this scenario. Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First insert dummy values in your php SQL statement & comment mysql_query statement.

   ```
   $sSql = "INSERT INTO comments (post_id,name,email,website,content) VALUES (100, 'anoop.pete','anoop.pete@gmail.com', 'www.anooppete.com', 'Nice Website' )";
   //mysql_query($sSql);
   //$update=mysql_affected_rows();
   ```
2. Print the SQL statement...

   ```
   print($sSql);
   ```
3. Copy the SQL statement from web browser, Execute the $sSql in MySql
4. If the row is inserted, in MySQL, uncomment  and run the same page again.

   ```
   mysql_query($sSql);
   $update=mysql_affected_rows();
   ```

If it runs, try removing htmlspecialchars()

```
    $users_name = $_POST['name'];
    $users_email = $_POST['email'];
    $users_website = $_POST['website'];
    $users_comment = $_POST['content'];
```

I guess your htmlspecialchars() is returning some invalid characters...

Comment: Thanks Anoop! If I have to validate the data before storing into a database in this case. How do I approach this?

Comment: You can use JavaScripts to validate

Answer (score 0):

-1 means the query returned an error.

Put this sql query into your sql browser's sql 'querier' and see what the error is:

```
INSERT INTO 
comments
(post_id,
name,
email,
website,
content)
VALUES 
(2, 
'name',
'email@', 
'http://', 
'comment')
```